# How to find the size of the dataframe in spark streaming jobs

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to find the size of the dataframe in spark streaming jobs in each batch. I am able to find the the size in the batch jobs successfully, but when it comes to streaming I am unable to do this.

I have been developing spark application on databricks and tried 'df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes' in streaming job. 
But am getting the following exception : 
 Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;

I have tried putting 'df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes' inside the forEachBatch() function :

```
data.writeStream.foreachBatch { (df: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
df.persist() 
println("The size of the read is : " + df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes)                              
}.start.option("checkpointLocation", outpath + "/_checkpoint")
```

But this will create a new stream, which we need to avoid due to some constraints.

```
val data = spark.readStream
                .format("kafka") 
                .option(....)
                .load()

println("The size of the read is : " + data.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.stats.sizeInBytes)
```

Is there any hack or any api call that returns the size of the dataframe in streaming without the use of "forEachBatch()" or without creating a new stream ?

Comment: Care to elaborate on _"But this will create a new stream, which we need to avoid due to some constraints."_?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Following

Few Imports

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator
```

Calculate Size of RDD

```
def calcRDDSize(rdd: RDD[String]): Long = {
    rdd.map(_.getBytes("UTF-8").length.toLong)
    .reduce(_+_) //add the sizes together
}
```

Size is calculated as

```
val rdd1 = df.rdd.map(_.toString())
calcRDDSize(rdd1)
```

where df is your dataframe. It will estimate size in bytes.

Hope This helps :)

Comment: We won't get the exact size of the dataframe if we convert dataframe into rdd. Also, it changes the whole picture if you convert each row to a string.